# Robot Framework Execute Javascript Execution Error

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, robotframework

Any idea why I keep getting the below error, when I try to execute my robot test case?

> JavascriptException: Message: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument
> list

When I trie to execute the below keyword

```
     Execute Javascript  document.getElementByXpath('//button[contains(.,'Help')]').onclick();
```

Comment: single quotes inside single quotes aren't doing what you think they are doing.

Comment: Because you didn't put quotes around it, and the JS interpreter tries to evaluate it as an expression. Surround it with quotes, or, even better, set a click listener using jQuery's .click method.

Answer (score 2):

You've used single quotes for both the argument of `getElementByXpath()` and the xpath's `contains()` function; this closed the js function's call unexpectedly. Change one to use double quotes:

```
document.getElementByXpath("//button[contains(.,'Help')]").onclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
JavascriptException: Message: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

...implies that there was a syntax error within the expression.

You need to replace the outer single quote i.e. `'...'` with double quote i.e. `"..."` as follows:

```
Execute Javascript  document.getElementByXpath("//button[contains(.,'Help')]").onclick();
```

As an alternative you can also use `document.evaluate()` as follow`:

```
Execute JavaScript document.evaluate('//button[contains(.,"Help")]',document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

---

### Outro

[Clicking Element with JavaScript on Robot Framework](https://medium.com/@gvasanka/clicking-element-with-javascript-on-robot-framework-bdcf666ec4e2)